# Maintaining same consumer group while migrating from Mirror maker 1.0 to Mirror maker 2.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Was trying to upgrade mirror maker 1.0 to mirror maker 2.0 and observed that on shutting down mirror maker 1.0 and starting mirror maker 2.0 the consumer starts getting messages from the beginning(duplicates). Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017214/maintaining-same-offset-while-migrating-from-confluent-replicator-to-apache-mirr) highlighting the same issue.
a. How to pass the `consumer group name` in mirror maker 2.0 to keep the same `consumer group name` as being used in mirror maker 1.0?
b. How to configure the `auto.offset.reset` property in mirror maker 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You can't directly reuse the consumer group from MM1 with MM2 because MM2 does not use a consumer group, it's a Kafka Connect connector.

b) `auto.offset.reset` is not currently configurable in MM2. It will be configurable in the next release, 2.7.0, which is expected to release very soon (as a Dec 17, a vote on the release candidate is on-going).

From 2.7.0, it will be configurable using `<alias>.consumer.auto.offset.reset` or `consumer.auto.offset.reset` in your configuration.

Comment: _does not use a consumer group, it's a Kafka Connect **Source** connector_, right? Sinks do use consumer groups

Comment: tried using name in the mirror-maker properties to set consumer group but it didn't show up in consumer groups when i listed them.